# Repeating controls with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, windows

I've been into web for long, but now I should do a little c# project and I'm wondering how I can make such repeat:

[image]

In web I can just do

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and even add it dynamicly:

```
var items = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
for ( var i in items ) {
     $("#holder").append("<div class=\"item\"></div>");
}
```

and render as much items as represented in the array.

My actual question is how to use exactly User Control?

Comment: Please add more tags ASP.Net/WebForms/ASP.Net-mvc/maybe even something else.

Comment: `loop{ var c = new SomeControl(); someParentControl.Controls.Add(c); }`

Comment: You have so many options in C#, which include just repeating the markup and a loop to add items. You need to clarify what platform/tools you are using, and explain what kind of data you have and what isn't obvious about how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a UserControl (Add > New Item... > User Control)

```
public partial class WFUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

[image: user control]

And add on a container control, such as a panel

```
panel1.Controls.Add(new WFUserControl());
```

To make it add one bellow another you can use a `TableLayoutPanel`, set `AutoSize` to `true`, set only one column and only one row. Then when you add 3 controls it will look like this:

[image: table layout panel]

Comment: Just 1 more question: Since I will render them based on a List, how I can remove a item?

Comment: `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(control)` should work. Get the control from the list and call this method. You also have `RemoveAt`...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is according to your need but let's say you want to repeat the same template for items that you have pulled from database, you can use data list or list view.